# Predicting a value using certain x values in multiple Linear regression in sas

Tags: sas

In a multiple linear regression problem i have to predict a value using x1=77, x2=20, x3=1998
The code I currently have is

```
PROC reg Data=GPA;
   model y=x1 x2 x3/i;
   Output out=new3 student=student2 p=predict2 r=resid2;
 Run;
```

The code runs but I’m not sure how to use the input values to predict another value

Comment: You should make use of code comment formatting for easier readability.

Comment: Add an observation with missing Y and x1-x3 set as desired (77,20,1998) to data GPA.  data NEW3 will have predicted value.

Comment: How would you do that in code I’m having trouble understanding how to code that. And sorry to how the question was typed, I was doing it on a phone and wasn’t sure how

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

An easy way to do this is to add a new row to your data set using the following code:

```
proc sql;
    insert into test (x1, x2, x3) values (77, 20, 1998);
quit;
```

Then run the model again and you should get your predicted value for y.